# Using Jmol in Android application

Tags: java, android, libraries

I would like to use the [Jmol](http://wiki.jmol.org/index.php/Main_Page) open source molecular viewer library for visualizations within an Android application. I have not been able to find any resources that describe the use of Jmol in Android applications or even in just Java applications.

Am I mistaken in that Jmol can be used as I propose? Can you point me to any resources such as tutorials or the like that would assist me?